# Unhandled Exception: Unable to getUserMedia: getUserMedia(): DOMException, NotAllowedError

Tags: flutter, webrtc, getusermedia

We're trying to make a video conferencing app.
When running the app on Windows for testing, the video turns on just fine but when we run it on a physical device (an Android phone), the following error comes up and the video does not show.

E/flutter ( 1917): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: Unable to getUserMedia: getUserMedia(): DOMException, NotAllowedError

E/flutter ( 1917): #0      MediaDeviceNative.getUserMedia (package:flutter_webrtc/src/native/mediadevices_impl.dart:29:7)

E/flutter ( 1917):

E/flutter ( 1917): #1      _MeetingPageState.startMeeting (package:attempt2/pages/meeting_page.dart:56:32)

E/flutter ( 1917):

E/flutter ( 1917):

Comment: have you added permissions in AndroidManifest file?

Comment: @Yashraj thank you, that was the issue, i forgot to add permissions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't forget to add device permissions in the Android Manifest file.

Answer (score 4):

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

Ensure the following permission is present in your Android Manifest file, located in `<project root>/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:`